# Passing jQuery variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables, undefined

I'm facing some problems with jquery and javascript interoperability.

I have a piece of code that attempts to create a PNG from the canvas and write it to a variable.

```
jQuery.getScript('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js', function() {
    //script is loaded and executed put your dependent JS here
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
    var mapcanvas = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'mapimg',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        lon: center[1].toFixed(6),
        lat: center[0].toFixed(6),
        zoom: zoominfo.zoom,
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true
    });

    var getbasemapimg = mapcanvas.getCanvas().toDataURL('image/png');
    alert("Inside jQuery: " + getbasemapimg);
});
```

This works fine inside the jQuery section above (the alert returns `getbasemapimg` in its base64 string format), but further along in the script, I attempt to call the `getbasemapimg` variable and this time it says it's undefined:   `getbasemapimg is not defined`

I had to wrap the first section up in jQuery as it was calling an external javascript source and I could figure out how to get it to work without employing jQuery.

I think I need to set the value `getbasemapimg` globally but can't work out how to do it.

Comment: where are you calling the variable, share that code. Either you can make variable global or you can pass it as function parameter

Comment: Scope is related to the place of declaration in javascript. To make it global scope, place it at top most level. Refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-variable-scopes-in-javascript/) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have access to mapboxgl in your scope. Your code is called as a callback after the library is requested via Ajax. You can add that library in your index.html via a  tag BEFORE your own code as a simple solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to load the script in the HMTL  before the mapbox instantiating